# How many strings of length $5$ can I make out of the letters A,B and C (if I am allowed to use letters more than once)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Hi can you help me with this question:
How many strings of length 5 can I make out of the letters A,B and C (if I am allowed to use letters more than once)?

Comment: So for each of the 5 characters you have $3$ choices, right? What can you conclude from that? Btw,  you should remove all tags and give it e.g. tag "combinatorics".

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question by means of an edit (not a comment), and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You have five letters to pick.

For the first letter, you have 3 choices: A, B and C.
For the second letter, you also have 3 choices: A, B and C. That means you have $3 \times 3 = 9 = 3^2$ different choices at this point.
For the third letter, you still have 3 choices: A, B and C. That means you have $9 \times 3 = 27 = 3^3$ choices.

Etc.

In general, being able to pick $n$ times among $m$ choices gives you $m^n$ possibilities. Here, your answer is $3^5$

Comment: I'd like to add that the given answer is utilizing the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product#:~:text=In%20combinatorics%2C%20the%20rule%20of,ways%20of%20performing%20both%20actions.).